# How to solve branch/trunk conflict with Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, conflict

I have a very easy conflict in Tortoise SVN, but I don't see an easy way to solve it.

I have 2 development threads, lets say trunk and branch. The same file is deleted both in trunk and branch, so it looks likes this file is not needed and should not cause any problems. However, now Tortoise SVN disallows me to reintegrate a branch.

I really don't need this file, so it looks natural to remove it, so I click Delete item in context menu. However, Tortoise SVN shows me message that "Node ... was not found." Ok, I click "Edit conflicts" item in context menu, however, it gives no chance to really solve this conflict, the only working buttons here are "Show log" and "Mark as solved".

So, how such conflicts are solved with Tortoise SVN at all? In documentation they write a lot about conflicts classification, but nothing about a very easy situation when not needed file is removed in both trunk and branch and when it looks very logical to not create conflict at all and just remove this file in merged copy.

Answer (score 2):

The file is already deleted, so "Mark as resolved" is what you want to do: just tell SVN that it's ok as it is (the file is deleted).

Comment: `+1` from me. Can't argue with the guy who wrote the thing. `:)`

Comment: SVN disallows me to do it; when I mark conflict as "resolved", it appears again on next commit.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can only reintegrate a branch into the trunk (or whatever ancestor it derived from) after you have merged all changes from the trunk (ancestor) into the branch you want to reintegrate. Have you done that?

If you have done the same change in both branch/trunk, and get a hard to resolve conflict when merging, you can advise SVN to skip this one change when merging, by recording the merge without actually performing it. (Option "Only record the merge" in TSVN.)

Comment: Hi, thanks you, so: 1. I have to merge trunk to branch. 2. I have to merge branch back to trunk?

Comment: @user1089715: You will have to merge into the branch before you reintegrate.